# Google Places Library vs Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

What is the different between the Google Places Library and the Google Places API? I see that with the API, the search limit per 24 hour period is 100,000 searches where the Library the limit is per user and not per API key. Is it possible to use the places library within an android application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) is part of the Google Maps Javascript API v3, meant to be used in applications using that.

The [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) is a web service.

Comment: I would just add that they are quite related. The Google Places Library is just an implementation of useful client features that interact with the Google Places API. You can interact with the API on its own without the Google Places Library, or choose to use the library to accomplish your goals in Javascript quickly.

Answer (score 0):

i recently learn't that you would want to use Google Places API when you want to do more than just query for places information, like add new places to the maps database. the limit is 1000/day per app key.

google places library is what u use when u just want to query for existing places. the limit is 25000/day per user.

Comment: so can we use google places library in Android App..Will it work? OR using Google Place API is the only option?

Comment: U can if u can run javascrpit in android app.