# Google Places api usage limits and a calling error

Tags: android, ios, api, google-maps, google-places-api

I am developing android application (in the future iOS also) and when i started reading about the Google Places API , i saw that they have a usage limit for the Places AutoComplete.
https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/usage

As i saw there's 150,000 requests per 24 hour for the app itself.Meaning that if i got 150k users registered and each one of them made a request. My app has finished her request limit value.
As a programmer normal behavior i looked at this site and also google about this subject and i saw this post:
[Google Places Library vs Google Places API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093133/google-places-library-vs-google-places-api)

The guy that posted last there said that each user have 150,000 requests , but i wanted to confirm this with a question of my own.
If his answer is incorrect , is there another way of letting each user freely make requests for the Google Places api and also requests places by radius if needed?
Also i saw few places that said i can work without the api itself that the google play services gives me and work with the 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/ 
and all i need is to add parameters , but still is usage limits takes affect on this also?

Also , my second issue is when i execute this code as android app in the onCreate method this app crashes

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                    }
                })
                .build();

        PendingResult result = Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient , "New-York",null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation of the usage limits of the Places API for Android: https://developers.google.com/places/android/usage

Regarding your crash, I'd recommend checking the logs with "adb logcat" for errors explaining your crash.

Here are a few things to check:

- call `connect()` on `mGoogleApiClient` and wait for it to be connected before calling `getAutocompletePredictions()`
- get an *Android* API key for your app: https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup
- enable "Places API for Android" in the Developer Console
- set up your API key in your manifest (https://developers.google.com/places/android/start)

I hope this helps!